# Can I limit the number of my own custom resources that can be created with a ResourceQuota?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

If I have a custom resource definition like this:

```
$ kubectl get crd unifiedpushservers.push.aerogear.org
NAME                                   CREATED AT
unifiedpushservers.push.aerogear.org   2019-06-05T13:39:23Z
```

Is it possible to create a `ResourceQuota` that would limit the count of this type of custom resource to 1, refusing attempts to create additional ones?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: unifiedpushservers-limit
spec:
  hard:
    count/unifiedpushservers.push.aerogear.org: 1
```

While this get accepted and created, it seems like the counting doesn't work and I'm able to create more than one instance.

---

**Edit:** If I quote the integer value of the field in the spec, like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: unifiedpushservers-limit
spec:
  hard:
    count/unifiedpushservers.push.aerogear.org: "1"
```

then I get the following error message when trying to create even one instance:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "./deploy/crds/push_v1alpha1_unifiedpushserver_cr.yaml": unifiedpushservers.push.aerogear.org "example-unifiedpushserver" is forbidden: status unknown for quota: unifiedpushservers-limit
```

That feels like progress, but I might be getting further away, I'm not sure.

Also, I should mention that I'm trying this on an OpenShift v3.11 cluster, which returns the following Kubernetes version info:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11+", GitVersion:"v1.11.0+d4cacc0", GitCommit:"d4cacc0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-10-10T16:38:01Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11+", GitVersion:"v1.11.0+d4cacc0", GitCommit:"d4cacc0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-11-09T15:12:26Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Hi, I do not think this is possible yet.

Comment: Here is the table of possible resources https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/#object-count-quota

Comment: @SureshVishnoi thanks for your input. I saw that page alright, but I still think it should be possible. The first line there is "The 1.9 release added support to quota all standard namespaced resource types [...]", and I'm using the listed syntax. I've added some new information to the question now also, which give me more conviction that this should be possible.

Comment: you need to append the RBAC, if its forbidden

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "append the RBAC"? Without the ResourceQuota I'm able to create instances of my CR, and once I've created the ResourceQuota I'm forbidden because the ResourceQuota has a "status unknown", so it sounds like it's waiting for a controller to update the status, right?

Comment: The controller should be able to write the status of the resourcequota. If I understand the error correctly,  this is the issue. we can check the rbac of the controller

Comment: @SureshVishnoi it turns out that you were right: this isn't possible...yet! It will be available in Kubernetes v1.15, per this pull request: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/72384 (it's in v1.15.0-alpha.1, according to this changelog: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.15.md#v1150-alpha1)

Comment: Hi @Gerard Ryan, just wanted  to provide the reference in the answer, if other people wanted to know about it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since **kubernetes 1.15** Object count quota is now supported for **namespaced custom resources** using the `count/<resource>.<group>` syntax

> For example, to create a quota on a widgets custom resource in the example.com API group, use count/widgets.example.com.

[object-count-quota](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/#object-count-quota)